# How to ping a server from within form application, then display true/false result?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, ping

This is likely a misunderstanding of the fundamentals on my part so any criticism is welcome.

I want to have a button that will check to see if one of our servers is up/down then display the result in a label.

Would it be possible to use **ping** for this then somehow assign 'true' in a label if there are packets received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal ICMP Ping is probably not what you want here. Servers are often configured to not respond to ping, and what you likely really want is to check if a certain *service* on the server is running. (If the system is booted, but your service is crashed, you probably don't want to report 'good'.)

I would suggest that you make a connection to the service you're interested in. Best would be if you can make a true connection and talk the proper protocol, but if all you can do is to open a TCP connection, that will at least tell you that the service is running.